# Adding property to array Object

Tags: javascript

Currently I have an array object`[{}]` code for the which is

```
const updatedDat = response.data
const updatedData = []
for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
    updatedData.push(updatedDat[i])
}
console.log(updatedData)
```

The console.log above logs

```
Array(5)
0:{userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit", body: "quia et suscipit↵suscipit recusandae consequuntur …strum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"}

1:{userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse", body: "est rerum tempore vitae↵sequi sint nihil reprehend…aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"}

2:{userId: 1, id: 3, title: "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut", body: "et iusto sed quo iure↵voluptatem occaecati omnis e…↵molestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"}

3:{userId: 1, id: 4, title: "eum et est occaecati", body: "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci↵sit … ipsam iure↵quis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"}

4:{userId: 1, id: 5, title: "nesciunt quas odio", body: "repudiandae veniam quaerat sunt sed↵alias aut fugi…sse voluptatibus quis↵est aut tenetur dolor neque"}
length:5
```

Now I want to add another field inside this object **named author** hence this should look like this

```
1:{Author:"Max" userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse", body: "est rerum tempore vitae↵sequi sint nihil reprehend…aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `updatedDat[i].Author = "Max";`

Comment: Maybe you want `updatedDat[i].author = "Max"` ? Is the name supposed to be the same for all objects?

Comment: The same way you add a property to any other object. Why do you think this is complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code should be help you if we have to add property which in array element  then must be add in 0 index

```js
const updatedDat = [{id:"1"}];
  updatedDat[0].auther = "some name"
    const updatedData = []
    for (let i=0; i<updatedDat.length; i++) {
        updatedData.push(updatedDat[i])
    }
    console.log(updatedData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by a simple forEach loop:

```
updatedData.forEach((obj)=>{
  obj.Author = "max";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add that key to a specific object in your array:

```
let arr = [
  {name: 'will', id: 1},
  {name: 'bill', id: 2}
];

const foundItem = arr.find(item => item.id === 1);
foundItem.author = 'foo';

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop add the property before inserting it.

```
for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
    updatedDat[i].Author = "Max";
    updatedData.push(updatedDat[i])
}
```